# Is there a tool for cleaning BibTeX source from LaTeX style escapes?

Tags: bibtex, unicode, tools, sourcecode

I have a BibTeX file which uses the old style LaTeX escapes, for example

> author = {Fjeld, Morten and Sch\"{a}r, Sissel Guttormsen}

I want to read the file with a Scala script using jbibtex and do some stuff with the information from it. But the escapes are getting in the way, and I don't want to implement my own replacement for all possible LaTeX escapes, if I can avoid it.

Is there a tool which can be fed LaTeX or BibTeX source, will replace all escaped umlauts and other such with the correct UTF-8 characters, and spit it out without any other changes? I can imagine that my use case is somewhat exotic, but maybe such a tool exists for people who want to convert their old manuscripts to modern technology.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `biber` to do this.  On a command line type

```
biber --tool --output_encoding=UTF-8 myfile.bib
```

For `myfile.bib` containing:

```
@Article{Schroeder:Na,
  author =   {Schr{\"o}der, M.},
  title =    {Na{\"i}ve construction of hyper{K\"ahler} metrics},
  journal =  {{\'E}c. Norm. Sup.},
  year =     2000
}
```

you will get an output file `myfile_bibertool.bib` containing:

```
@ARTICLE{Schroeder:Na,
  AUTHOR       = {Schröder, M.},
  JOURNALTITLE = {Éc. Norm. Sup.},
  TITLE        = {Naïve  construction of hyper{Kähler} metrics},
  YEAR         = {2000},
}
```

So the German and French accents are successfully translated.  As egreg notes `\"i` is the correct modern latex way to write the double dotted i - the old plain TeX way of `\"\i` will not be correctly converted by `biber` out of the box.

In tool mode, biber can be persuaded to do other rewriting of your source, see the biber manual `texdoc biber`.

Comment: If the ‘more correct’ input `{\"i}` is used, then biber is able to translate it into `ï`. Also `hyper{K\"a}hler` should be input as `{hyperK{\"a}hler}`.

Comment: @egreg Writing `{hyperK...}` prevents case change of the initial `h` which is usually not desirable.  If using `biber` of course you don't need any of the brackets.  You are right about `\"i`, but in a usual text document one needs `\"\i` to select the dotless i and not get a three dots at once.

Comment: Then use `hyper{K{\"a}hler}` (no problem with possible kerning between `r` and `K`). In normal LaTeX documents `\"i` produces `ï`: try and believe. The `\i` is not needed also with `\'i`, `\^i` and ``\`i``. Other accents need `\i`, though. It has been so for *several* years, but guides forgot to note the possibility.

Comment: @egre Thanks for the information about `\"i` - it does indeed work.   Where does one find that documented?  The hyperKähler bracketing is much better.

Comment: It's documented on page 456 of the LaTeX Companion. Not really prominent, I'd say. Unfortunately, the LaTeX manual has not been updated to make people aware of the possibility.